# Hibernate: How to get full sql query for session.save method?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm saving new object via Hibernate. What I would like to get is full sql query which was use. In debug Im getting query with "?" .

```
 ... values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

How to get same query with values.

K.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/). A simple query in a search engine of your choice would've given you that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from my log4j configuration (Hibernate 3.6.8).

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG, C
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder = TRACE, C
log4j.appender.C = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.C.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}] %-5p %C.%M : %m%n
```

SQL has the logger for the SQL statement (you need to set it to DEBUG level) and BasicBinder the logger for the actual parameters (TRACE level)

Comment: .. that was very helpfull

# logs the SQL statements
**log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug**

# Logs the JDBC parameters passed to a query
**log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace**

Comment: Also note, that setting the show_sql property of your hibernate configuration to true is not a good solution because the queries are not always printed in synch with the parameters printed by the BasicBinder logger. It is better to leave it to false and enable these two loggers.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
 <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

to **hibernate.cfg.xml** to show **SQL Query**

Comment: I have this on and it is showing question marks instead of values.